# android task kill

Tags: android, task, kill, taskkill

I want to kill all tasks that run in android like task killer...
What I have done until now is:

```
ActivityManager manager =  (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> activityes = ((ActivityManager) manager).getRunningAppProcesses();

    for (int i = 0; i < activityes.size(); i++){

        Log.e("APP: "+i, activityes.get(0).processName);

        if (!activityes.get(0).processName.equals("app.android.myapp")){
            Process.killProcess(activityes.get(0).pid);
        }

    }
```

The problem with the code is that it returns in the activityes list only my app for 12 times. 
And no task is being killed...

Can somebody help me please?
Thank you!

Comment: So, is there no way to kill other tasks on Android? @Cata: Did you find out how this could be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not have the rights to kill other processes; hence, `killProcess()` does not work for your app.

Comment: yes but it didn't supose to do a force close? I have android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" permission, and in the log I can see: com.svox.pico
  Sending signal. PID: 328 SIG: 9
  jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn
  Sending signal. PID: 141 IG: 9
 system
  Sending signal. PID: 71 SIG: 9
  com.android.defcontainer
 Sending signal. PID: 176 SIG: 9
 com.android.launcher
  Sending signal. PID: 190 SIG: 9
android.process.media
 Sending signal. PID: 260 SIG: 9
 com.android.quicksearchbox
: Sending signal. PID: 234 SIG: 9
 com.android.protips
 Sending signal. PID: 243 SIG: 9
 ...

Comment: @Cata: "yes but it didn't supose to do a force close?" -- no. Please read the documentation for `killProcess()`.

Comment: I have read it, and it says "Kill the process with the given PID." and it doesn't say that I need some rights...

Comment: @Cata: You need to learn how to read. The full Javadoc is: "Kill the process with the given PID. Note that, though this API allows us to request to kill any process based on its PID, the kernel will still impose standard restrictions on which PIDs you are actually able to kill. Typically this means only the process running the caller's packages/application and any additional processes created by that app; packages sharing a common UID will also be able to kill each other's processes."

Comment: Sorry CommonsWare, you are right I didn't read the full doc... thank you for the help!

Comment: @CommonsWare same question i have i want to kill process but could not kill so,  its not possible any helps appreciate me .

Answer (score 4):

You're using **0** (zero) instead of **i** inside your loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < activityes.size(); i++){

    Log.e("APP: "+i, activityes.get(i).processName);

    if (!activityes.get(i).processName.equals("app.android.myapp")){
        Process.killProcess(activityes.get(i).pid);
    }

}
```

Cheers

Comment: Yes, now I had noticed =)) I am so dizzy today... the problem is that this don't close the apps. Now I can see them but this code dont close them.

Answer (score 2):

You can kill the current process on back pressed using the following code:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

Comment: why on back pressesd, is it some kind of hack?!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to kill your task or app:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(ctx.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
```

this works for 2.2 and up.

Answer (score 0):

**1- Add to manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
```

**2 - In your code**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell killall com.example.app");
```

note that your app need to have access to adb shell (system app)