# How do Task Managers kill apps?

Tags: android, taskmanager

First of all I know it's bad to use a task manager/killer in Android and all that, but what I was wondering is how do task managers like `Advanced Task Killer` kill other applications?
I wanted to develop a simple application that would do this, just for the learning experience.
I tried executing the Linux command **kill pid** from my application but it didn't work, maybe it requires root?

So, how do I accomplish this from my application? I have a simple ListActivity that shows the currently running tasks and when a user long-presses an item I want to kill that task.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921244/android-task-kill, which covers this.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already read that post :) It doesn't answer my question though, the Process.killProcess function only allows one to kill my own process and not others, if I'm not wrong. I also tried it on my application but it didn't work :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can send the signal using:

```
Process.sendSignal(pid, Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
```

To completely kill the process, it's recommended to call:

```
ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(PackageName)
```

before sending the signal.

Comment: where is ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses... it says that the method is undefined...

Comment: so does this really kill external applications? I'm not quit sure how to check this. ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(PackageName); Process.sendSignal(pid, Process.SIGNAL_KILL);

Comment: does it? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

slayton has good answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502340/how-do-task-killers-work).I add this detail to his answer:
- when you use `ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(PackageName)` , you can not kill foreground process.

I saw these open sources project link in K_Anas'answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494626/android-task-manager-source):
- [github repository](https://github.com/todoroo/astrid)
- [code.google](http://code.google.com/p/freetaskmanager/)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid)
```

that will work...

Answer (score -2):

**1- Add to manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
```

**2 - In your code**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell killall com.example.app");
```

**Note :**  Your app needs to have access to adb shell system/app (root permission)

Comment: You need to have root permission for this