# Kill another process/application programmatically

Tags: android

I don't want to get on the discussion of whether a process can be killed by the user, whether it should be done that way or not.

I just want to know how almost every Android player's phone got a '`advanced task killer`' which kills a process or how is it that the `force close` (in settings) option works just fine. I have tried many ways to kill a process, but all without result. But when I see these '`advanced task killer`' I can't figure out what's wrong on my side.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303615/how-do-task-managers-kill-apps

Comment: @anothem : I have seen that post and found that  Process.sendSignal(pid, Process.SIGNAL_KILL); gives an error that it cannot be resolved.

Comment: Can you show the exact error and stack trace?

Comment: Process.SIGNAL_KILL cannot be resolved, its an Compile time error (eclipse),am using API level 8

Comment: It's all in android.os since API Level 1. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html maybe, try writing it as: android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL

Comment: yes tried it already.no errors.but still does not work.any other solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8534/discussion-between-abhishekb-and-anothem)

Comment: Do you have this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" /> in your manifest?

Comment: You don't get to say that you don't care to get into "the discussion of whether a process can be killed by the user" and then turn around and complain when what you try doesn't work.  **Fundamentally, this is not something you are supposed to be trying to do** so if you are serious about it, you are going to have to open yourself to discussion about the limitations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40266669/5235263

Answer (score 21):

You can use the *[killBackgroundProcesses()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses%28java.lang.String%29)* method of [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html):

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    am.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
```

Please, note that your app needs to own the [KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES) permission. Thus, in the *AndroidManifest.xml*, you need to include:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

Comment: It does work, on **background** processes

Comment: Is there a way to kill other background processes (you can stop from UI in Settings)?

Comment: In my case it is not working. I have added permission in manifest as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try [android.os.Process](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29):

```
void killMyProcess() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

*As it implies from the method name, you can only kill your own process by using this approach.*

Comment: tried using it.does not help.the Process.killProcess function only allows me to kill my own process and not others

Comment: no error.it just does not work

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess(int) can only kill your own processes with this method

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have launched activities in the order A -> B -> C -> D with A as your main and launcher activity.

You can not even kill your application's process by calling `Process.KillProcess(int pid)` method in your D activity. You need to kill each activity D - C - B - A (in reverse order) to kill the process.

So killing other application processes is out of the question.

Comment: actually vishal its not even like that u must have tried finish().that does not kill the process.U can check that in the settings->Running tab.Ur application still remain in the background

Comment: "So killing other application processes is out of question"  thats my point.how does ' advanced task killer ' work then?

Comment: This is simply untrue.  **You can kill any process you own**, however Android may be surprised by this and as a result perhaps decide that it should start a replacement for the killed process.