# How to disable a specific app using android studio

Tags: android

I would like to create an app using android studio that disable some of the phone's other apps while running in the background. I have made several apps before, but none of them interacted with any other apps on the phone. I have looked online and not found any useful links. All help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Sounds suspicious! Would the uses choose which apps to disable? Or does your app do it without their knowledge?

Comment: The user can ultimately choose, but this doesn't affect the answer to the question.

Comment: May be this answers be some sort of help:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036895/kill-another-application-on-android), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563404/kill-another-process-application-programmatically)