# Get Running Processes List and Kill Their Background Services

Tags: android, service, garbage-collection, background-process

I am building an Android app for RAM optimization. I can successfully get the list of running processes (and their PIDs) using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3479710/1514026). However, I don't see a way to kill them or their background services by PID.

Comment: Try here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720164/android-process-killer

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9804786/1321873

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turned out to be something very basic:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

for (RunningAppProcessInfo pid : am.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
    am.killBackgroundProcesses(pid.processName);
}
```