# Can I suspend another application's process from my android application?

Tags: android

I am planning to write an application that keeps tracks of all the applications and halts or suspends the process of an application if it is consuming more CPU time or consuming more threads than necessary.

Is it possible to halt or suspend another application's process that is running continuously in the background with our application?

Comment: hey! I am new to android and a student also,so please do not down vote the question because i am trying to learn something from this platform, comment why the question is aberrant,or modify if you have enough reputation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I kill processes in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847502/how-can-i-kill-processes-in-android)

Comment: @syed Okay so before you post a question, search SO if anyone hasn't asked the question before you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892400/get-running-processes-list-and-kill-their-background-services http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720164/android-process-killer