# Android ZXING Exception handling

Tags: android, exception, zxing

I am working on an Android App which uses ZXING as external library. ZXING source code is not part of my application itself. I have setup ZXING project separately and refering that to my APP as android library.

My question is regarding exception handling/error handling related to ZXING. I know zxing already comes with some exception handling, but in case an uncaught exception occurs, I want to close my app along with ZXING. ZXING view remains active even when the app which called is killed. I can see the CaptureActivity layout still active, camera still scans.

How can I make sure that if my app crash & closes, it also closes ZXING ?.

Any advice on this front will be helpful.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10476164/2777098

Comment: I have tried, as per the SO thread above, but did't work. The last view was still active and when I launch the app again (Without Force Closing of course), app still has the zxing screen on, ready for scanning again.
I took another route and did exception handling in my app. Caught any uncaught exception arising anywhere (within my app or in zxing), and then close the application:-

 android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

 and launch the app again immediately. 
However I still wonder why I was not able to kill zxing completely.