# how do i get calling Activity name if it is a system app ( i.e gallery app )

Tags: android, gallery, onbackpressed, android-homebutton

i have searched a lot but i cant find answer so i thought i should post here.

**problem**

my app works on images which are share by gallery application(i.e default gallery app) and its works fine. but i want to override OnBackPress() method to check whether back button is pressed or not and if backbutton is pressed then i simply want to get calling activity name and want to kill that activity and go back to home.

i can do this if i call another activity form my activity but how can get calling activity name if it is a system app. (i.e gallery application)

keep in mind that my app called when i share images from gallery app so basically i want to get **gallery activity** to kill it and can go back home safely. *i dont wannna go back to gallery app.*

i want to simply go back to home and kill that gallery app instead of going back to gallery app.

here is **OnBackPressed() method**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do something on back.

    // what i tried so far but it is not working
    this.getParent().finish();
    this.finish();
}
```

i tired this and hopefully i can go back home safely but still gallery app run in background. i want to kill calling app too.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? You won't get cooked code here based on functionality or whatever.

Comment: Ever Heard of BackStack? You can make use of that or a simple google search "Finish all activity in android" would do just fine.

Comment: Make your home activity `SingleInstance` and Call it again with `Intent` in `onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
this.getParent().finish();
this.finish();
```

If this is not working you could try to add a filter in your intent before you open this explicit activity:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

Comment: it gives NullPointerException error. i want to kill calling activity and in my case calling activity is system gallery application

Comment: i appreciate your help but i want you to read question again because i dont start any intent. it will start when i select images from gallery and select my app from sharing option. so i dont start any intent at all. hope you understand

Comment: How are you opening the gallery?

Comment: As usual from launcher. 1) i open gallery 2) select some pictures 3) click on share button and pick my app from the list. BUT now when i press back button i want to kill gallery app and want to exit my app too.

Comment: Now I understand what you mind, give a few sec to think in a possible solution. I though you was launching the gallery through an explicit intent and the explicit intent is in your own app.

Comment: Check this link I think It could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804786/how-to-kill-a-3rd-party-application