# Does the Android sdk have functions that will clear devices caches, residual files and temporary files

Tags: java, android

I am building this app for a school project and I cannot seem to find the files on Android SDK website. Any steer in the write direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't think so. There's tons of apps out there that claim to do exactly this, I don't know what exactly they're doing but I think it's something that the SDK does not provide some vanilla methods for. 
Also it's not very clear what "residual" or "temporary" files are.

Comment: Do you want the app to clear all user data, bringing back the device to its factory configurations? Or just want to delete files and cache created by your own application?

Comment: The app must delete files and clear cache from other running apps @Plinio.Santos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to clear all private data from other running apps.

First of all, you can not do that in ordinary android devices. It will work only in rooted devices.

Besides of that, it's a dangerous operation because you are going to force an app to run into an unexpected state, since the developer may not had predicted get his app suddenly losing its private data.

Let's start with the real thing. You should kill the the app to avoid breakages. This post says how to do that:

[How do Task Managers kill apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303615/how-do-task-managers-kill-apps)

Then, you need to delete the app private folder `/data/data/<app_package_name>`:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
        "su", "-c", "rm -rf /data/data/<app_package_name>"});
proc.waitFor();
```