# How to kill/close a service of another android app

Tags: java, android, service, kill

I have an android app got it from Google play, I can kill this app from my app using:

```
 KillApplication("Appname");
```

But this app has a service keep running. I tried to kill this service by:

```
 KillApplication("Appname.serviceName");
```

But it doesn't kill the service "serviceName". Any suggestion please?

Edit: I just forgot to write the method "KillApplication"

```
public void KillApplication(String KillPackage)
{
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    am.killBackgroundProcesses(KillPackage);

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Task Manager's kill apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303615/how-do-task-managers-kill-apps)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in mainactivity.

```
ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(PackageName);
```

Add permissions in Manifest file

```
android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"
```