# Managing background running processes

Tags: android

I am trying to freeze background running processes when mobile screen is off and when screen get on processes should restart automatically in lower android versions. But i am not able to find any code to achieve this functionality.So if anyone knows about this then please help.

Comment: Don't show any notification in the notification bar. I will automatically be killed by the android. If you killed instantly create a broadcast as answered by @Juan Sancho and kill your service.

Comment: Let me know if you still stuck

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            //Stop your service
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // Start your service
        }
    }
}, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop your background service in `onStop()` method of activity life cycle by using `stopService(intent);` and again start in `onResume()` method of activity life cycle by using `startService(intent);`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i want to freeze all background running processes including other apps running processes

Comment: You can't control other app running process.

Comment: can i achieve this in lower android version?

Comment: i mean can i stop other apps running processes in lower version of android

Comment: As i said you can't control other app's running processes.

Comment: try this one but it won't work for me


ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(PackageName)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303615/how-do-task-managers-kill-apps

Comment: link u share is for kill background process but i want to freeze processes not want to kill but thanks for the answer

Comment: yes this is the only way to kill other apps process.